# Error Appending to Parquet File Using Dask Dataframe

Tags: python, dask, dask-dataframe

I'm new to Dask and I'm trying to append to a parquet file.... but my code consistently overwrites the contents of the file?

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

```py
print("Write dataframe 1...")
df = pd.DataFrame({'DeptId': [1, 2, 3], 'DName': ['Accounting', 'Sales', 'Finance'], 'DeptNo': [100, 200, 300]})
df.set_index(['DeptId'], inplace=True)
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, chunksize=1000)
print(ddf.head(3))
file_name = 'C:/Temp/xxx'
ddf.to_parquet(path=file_name, engine="pyarrow")

print("\nAppend dataframe 2...")
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'DeptId': [4, 5, 6], 'DName': ['Engineering', 'Support', 'Consulting'],
                    'DeptNo': [400, 500, 600]})
df2.set_index(['DeptId'], inplace=True)
ddf2 = dd.from_pandas(df2, chunksize=1000)
print(ddf2.head(3))
ddf2.to_parquet(path=file_name, engine="pyarrow", ignore_divisions=True, append=True, overwrite=False)

print("\nResulting parquet file...")
ddf3 = dd.read_parquet(path=file_name, engine="pyarrow")
print(ddf3.head())
```

The output is as follows...

- Write dataframe 1...

```
             DName  DeptNo
DeptId                    
1       Accounting     100
2            Sales     200
3          Finance     300
```

- Append dataframe 2...

```
              DName  DeptNo
DeptId                     
4       Engineering     400
5           Support     500
6        Consulting     600
```

- Resulting parquet file...

```
              DName  DeptNo
DeptId                     
4       Engineering     400
5           Support     500
6        Consulting     600
```

- I'm using this versions

```
python  3.8.8
dask    2020.3.1
pandas  1.2.3
pyarrow 3.0.0
```

Regards

MarkR

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that each file will be loaded as a separate partition, so when you run `.head()` it will look for values in the first partition only. In your case, you want to see all the obsevations so try one of the options below:

```py
print(ddf3.head(npartitions=2)) # note this will show only first 5 rows

# or

print(ddf3.head(6, npartitions=2)) # this will show first 6 rows (all of the sample data)

# or

print(ddf3.compute()) # another way to see all of the sample data
```

Comment: Sultan, thanks for the feedback.

I tried all of the suggestions without any luck.

I think the problem is on the 2nd write (i.e. the append) to the parquet file?

Comment: That's odd. I literally copy-pasted your code (my library version are same as yours) and attached my snippet at the end, and I see correct output on my end. The only difference is I'm on Mac and you seem to be on Windows...

Comment: I had a bright idea earlier today and changed the first to_parquet statement to include the append=True parameter and it worked!

`
ddf.to_parquet(path=file_name, engine="pyarrow", ignore_divisions=True, append=True, overwrite=False)
`
This now works and the read_parquet statement returns 6 records.

Thanks for your help.